# How to copy the month value from one Date object to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Given two Date objects, how to properly set the month of the first object to the month of another?

I'm facing a task of copying day, month and year from one Date object to another. Copying day and year works as intended, the problem comes up when I'm trying to copy the month.

Using `b.setMonth(a.getMonth())` results in b having its month one too many.

Using `b.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 1)` however, results in b having its month one less than required.

The following typescript code:

```js
      let a = new Date(2018, 1, 12);
      let b = new Date();
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());

      b.setMonth(a.getMonth());

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());


      b.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 1);

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());
```

Returns:

```
Mon Feb 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100
Thu Aug 29 2019 16:11:03 GMT+0200
====
1
7
====
1
2
====
1
0                  // 2 - 1 = 0 ?
```

Seemingly 2 - 1 should give 1 `(a.getMonth() - 1)`, but apparently Date objects behave differently. What is the right way of copying month from one Date object to another in javascript/typescript? I suppose converting both dates to string, copying the right characters and parsing the string back to Date would work, but I'm wondering if there's an easier, more cleaner approach.

Comment: From your description it sounds like what you are really after is to make `b` have the same date value as `a`. If you are ok with copying over the "time of day" (hour, min, sec, ms) as well, you can simply use `a.setTime(b.getTime());`. That will effectively "clone" the exact timestamp from one date object to the other. You could even do this when you constuct "a" directly. `const a = new Date(b.getTime());`. [Docs for `setTime()` here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime)

Comment: Also, JavaScript `Date` is usually considered frustrating to work with.  Depending on how much you are actually doing with the date objects, it might be worth using a library to help make it simpler.  I recommend checking out [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).  It makes many things much simpler to do when working with dates in JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the `setMonth()` method has an optional second parameter which is the day ([DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)). If you don't provide a value for the day it will automatically use the one of the date.

So, your A date is 12 February 2018 while your B date is 29 August 2019.

By doing `b.setMonth(a.getMonth());` you are implicitly saying `b.setMonth(1,29);` (1 is a.getMonth() while 29 is the day form the b date).

So you are trying to set the date to the 29 February which isn't possible in 2019 and it shift the month by 1 to March (month 2).

If you do `b.setMonth(a.getMonth() -1);` you are setting it to the 29 January, which is possible so you get January as a month (month 1).

Answer (score 7):

It's because it's your lucky (or unlucky!) day. It's the particular dates you're working woith.

February only has 28 days this year. When you set the month of "Aug 29 2019" to February, you're trying to create the invalid date "Feb 29 2019". That gets rounded up to "Mar 1 2019".

If you'd tried this experiment yesterday, you wouldn't have seen this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the number of days in each month.

When you do:

```
b.setMonth(a.getMonth());
```

You are getting the b date but with february as the month: Thu Feb 29 2019 16:11:03 GMT+0200

And February of 2019 did not have 29 days. So the date is actually March 1st: Thu Mar 01 2019 16:11:03 GMT+0200

That is why you get month 2 in the second set of console logs.

And lastly you are setting b.month not a.month so it's subtracting one month from the a date (from February to January).

Answer (score 0):

because you use a.getMonth() instead of b.getMonth().
So your main month is 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

while setting month you also need to specify the day you can use this code instead

```js
var a = new Date(2018, 1, 12);
      var b = new Date();
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());

      b.setMonth(a.getMonth(),1);

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());


      b.setMonth(a.getMonth() - 1,1);

      console.log('====');
      console.log(a.getMonth());
      console.log(b.getMonth());
```